# How to fetch same data from large number of array and store that data to another array?

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I have large size of xml file like this,

```
<FEEDBACKLIST> 
<SUMMARY>
<MERCHANTIDENTIFIER>example-retail-merchant</MERCHANTIDENTIFIER>
<TOTALSERVICECOUNT>131</TOTALSERVICECOUNT>
<TOTALPRODUCTCOUNT>139</TOTALPRODUCTCOUNT>
<COUNT>130</COUNT>
<SUPPLIERLOGO>https://api.feefo.com/api/merchant-image/example-retail-
  merchant-logo.png</SUPPLIERLOGO>
<URL>https://www.feefo.com/reviews/example-retail-merchant</URL>
<TITLE>Example Retail Merchant</TITLE>
<BEST>100</BEST>
<WORST>0</WORST>
<AVERAGE>75</AVERAGE>
<START>1</START>
<LIMIT>20</LIMIT>
<SERVICEEXCELLENT>61</SERVICEEXCELLENT>
</SUMMARY>

<SUMMARY></SUMMARY>
<SUMMARY></SUMMARY>
<SUMMARY></SUMMARY>
</FEEDBACKLIST>
```

All attributes are repeated in  tag,
I'm already converted xml file in php array format, task is that I need to fetch  and  attribute data from array and store that data to another empty array, so how to get this result?

Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: try using json_encode()  to convert the array to a more portable format then json_decode() to convert it back to an array

Comment: yes i'm already do that,but still want to know how to fetch repeated data from large number of array and store to another array

Comment: Could you post the expected output please?

Comment: Also could you post part of the php array that you converted from XML?